# How to set up XAML bindings properly in a MAUI app

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, maui, reactiveui

I wrote a simple dictionary app with a single XAML page, then I decided to put the entries and translations into separate views with their own ViewmModels and the fun began.

Basically I managed to make everything work, but it just shows me these nagging XAML binding errors, I don't know why, AI went stupid on this, would much appreciate help!

> EntryModel has properties `Header` and `Subheader`

> TranslationModel has its own properties

Errors look like this:

```
Severity    Count   Data Context    Binding Path    Target  Target Type Description File    Line    Project

Error   50  EntryViewModel  Header  Label.Text  String  'Header' property not found on 'dosham.ViewModels.EntryViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'    C:\Users\x.dr\source\repos\movsar\chldr\src\chldr_maui\Views\EntryView.xaml 11  dosham

Error   50  EntryViewModel  Subheader   Label.Text  String  'Subheader' property not found on 'dosham.ViewModels.EntryViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text' C:\Users\x.dr\source\repos\movsar\chldr\src\chldr_maui\Views\EntryView.xaml 14  dosham

Error   50  EntryViewModel  Translations    StackLayout.ItemsSource IEnumerable 'Translations' property not found on 'dosham.ViewModels.EntryViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout.ItemsSource' C:\Users\x.dr\source\repos\movsar\chldr\src\chldr_maui\Views\EntryView.xaml 18  dosham

Error   50  EntryViewModel  .   EntryView.Entry EntryModel  'dosham.ViewModels.EntryViewModel' cannot be converted to type 'chldr_data.DatabaseObjects.Models.EntryModel'   C:\Users\x.dr\source\repos\movsar\chldr\src\chldr_maui\Pages\MainPage.xaml  24  dosham
```

I see it's saying that it can't find the Header and Subheader on my ViewModel, but it shouldn't be looking for them on the ViewModel, instead on my Entry and Translation models from ViewModel. How do I tell that without breaking the bindings that are working right now?

Also, if you have better suggestions on code organization - you're welcome to advice.

Here's the code:

**MainPage**

-- View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:dosham.ViewModels"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:dosham.Views"
             x:Class="dosham.Pages.MainPage">

    <Grid Padding="10">
        <!-- Define the rows -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- For CollectionView, takes remaining space -->
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <!-- For Search Box -->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Collection View for Entries -->
        <CollectionView x:Name="EntriesCollectionView" Grid.Row="0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredEntries}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <views:EntryView Entry="{Binding .}"></views:EntryView>
                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <!-- Search Box -->
        <Entry x:Name="SearchBox" Grid.Row="1"
         Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         Placeholder="Начните писать..." 
         Margin="0,0,0,10" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

-- Codebehind

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = App.Services.GetRequiredService<MainPageViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

-- ViewModel

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public IEnumerable<EntryModel> FilteredEntries
    {
        get => _filteredEntries;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _filteredEntries, value);
    }
....
```

**EntryView**

-- View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:dosham.Views"
             x:Class="dosham.Views.EntryView">
    
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Frame CornerRadius="10" Margin="5" Padding="10" BorderColor="#CACCaa" BackgroundColor="#f9F9F9">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="5">
                <!-- Entry Content -->
                <Label Text="{Binding Header}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#000" />

                <!-- Source Name -->
                <Label Text="{Binding Subheader}" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="#cba" />


                <!-- Translation views -->
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Translations}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <views:TranslationView Translation="{Binding .}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```

-- Codebehind

```
public partial class EntryView : ContentView
{
    private EntryViewModel _viewModel;

    public static readonly BindableProperty EntryProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(_viewModel.Entry), typeof(EntryModel), typeof(EntryView));

    public EntryView()
    {
        _viewModel = App.Services.GetRequiredService<EntryViewModel>();
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

-- ViewModel

```
 public class EntryViewModel : ViewModelBase
 {
     #region Properties, Actions and Constructors
     public EntryModel Entry { get; set; }
     ...
 }
```

**TranslationView**

-- View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dosham.Views"
             x:Class="dosham.Views.TranslationView">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Language Code Label -->
        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                  Text="{Binding LanguageCode, StringFormat='{0}:'}" 
                  FontSize="Small" 
                  FontAttributes="Italic" 
                  TextColor="#AA6666" />

        <!-- Content Label -->
        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                  Text="{Binding Content, StringFormat=' {0}'}" 
                  FontSize="Small" 
                  TextColor="#666666" />
    </Grid>

</ContentView>
```

-- Codebehind

```
public partial class TranslationView : ContentView
{
    private readonly TranslationViewModel _viewModel;

    public static readonly BindableProperty TranslationProperty =
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(_viewModel.Translation), typeof(TranslationModel), typeof(TranslationView));

    public TranslationView()
    {
        _viewModel = App.Services.GetRequiredService<TranslationViewModel>();
        BindingContext = _viewModel;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

-- ViewModel

```
public class TranslationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public TranslationViewModel(ContentStore contentStore, UserStore userStore) : base(contentStore, userStore)
    { }
    public TranslationModel Translation { get; set; }
....
}
```

Here's the visual:
[image]

Comment: should be `Text="{Binding Entry.Header}"`

Comment: @Jason if I change like this - it doesn't even work

Comment: What does "doesn't even work" mean?  Does it not compile?  Does it throw an exception?  Does the previous error message go away?  You posted a LOT of code so its difficult to determine what all the problems might be, I just focused on the most immediate one that was producing the error message.

Comment: To get rid of `Binding` warnings and to get assistance from both the compilation and IDE intellisense, you should strive to set `x:DataType`. That will remove any ambiguity where your `Binding` are coming from.

Comment: @Jason it means, the app works well as it is, it just shows the Binding errors, but when I do as you say, then it stops working too

Comment: @StephenQuan added DataType, no change

Comment: Why do you use ViewModels for your ContentViews? It's not a common thing to do, usually only Pages have ViewModels while Views either inherit the parent BindingContext or receive a Model instance as a BindingContext. Of course, it's still possible to have ViewModels for ContentViews, it just makes things complicated. Your EntryView should have an EntryModel as a BindingContext, if you ask me (this is from a design perspective). You're basically redefining the BindingContext when you resolve the ViewModel. Then, your EntryView would ideally expose bindable properties, e.g. for commands.

Comment: @Julian you're probably right, I will try your solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two weeks of suffering and frustration, I ended up with a genius solution - got rid of the EntryView and TranslationView converting both of them to DataTemplates for better performance, then created a single view to hold the whole thing - EntriesView with a EntriesViewModel.

I also changed ContentView to reactive:ReactiveContentView and ContentPage to reactive:ReactiveContentPage.

The resulting code looks like this:

**MainPage**

```
public partial class MainPage : ReactiveContentPage<MainPageViewModel>
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.Services.GetRequiredService<MainPageViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();

        // Reactive bindings
        this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
        {
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.FilteredEntries, v => v.entriesView.ViewModel!.Entries);
        });
    }
}
```

**EntriesView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<reactive:ReactiveContentView   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                                xmlns:viewModels ="clr-namespace:dosham.ViewModels"
                                xmlns:reactive="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.Maui;assembly=ReactiveUI.Maui"
                                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                                x:TypeArguments="viewModels:EntriesViewModel"
                                x:Class="dosham.Views.EntriesView">

    <CollectionView x:Name="EntriesCollection"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EntryTemplate}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
    </CollectionView>

</reactive:ReactiveContentView>
```

**Codebehind**

```
public partial class EntriesView : ReactiveContentView<EntriesViewModel>
{
    public EntriesView()
    {
        ViewModel = App.Services.GetRequiredService<EntriesViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel** (ViewModelBase inherits from **ReactiveObject**)

```
public class EntriesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IEnumerable<EntryModel> _entries;
    public IEnumerable<EntryModel> Entries
    {
        get => _entries;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _entries, value);
    }
}
```

Works perfectly well :)

Comment: Excellent! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like...

`<Label Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:EntryViewModel}}, Path=Header}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#000" />`

Note: I'm not where I can test this right now, so can't verify the accuracy of my answer.

Comment: I believe you're confusing MAUI with WPF

Comment: @MovsarBekaev relative bindings are supported by MAUI, too.